# Unbalanced target variable in Orange, how do I balance it?

Tags: orange, class-imbalance

So I want to perform a predictive model to predict churn.

I have 2 datasets, one with churn and the other without (so I can later perform predictions).

The issue is that I think my Confusion matrix is kinda bad since my target variable is highly unbalanced:

[image]

which mostly leads to this confussion matrix:

[image]

(Similar values for both logistic regression and decision tree).

This is my workflow:

[image]

Is there any way to balance the data? I can't find it in the Orange documentation.

Comment: More methods are described here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/quick-guide-into-training-highly-imbalanced-data-sets

Answer (score 1):

For unbalanced classes use the Python Script widget, with imblearn add-on, you will need to code!

[Link for thread in github](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/2995)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to randomly delete samples from the majority class until there's a 50-50 split in the data. Then you can proceed to split 75% - 25% for training and testing.

You can also try to generate more Yes samples via imputation or whatever means may be relevant to the given dataset.

Sometimes you have to make the most out of the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

To balance the classes check Stratified sampling checkbox in [Data Sampler](https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/data/datasampler.html) widget. Note, it only works when downsampling